# How to capture Appium's terminal output?

Tags: javascript, testing, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

Is there any way to capture the terminal output after appium test scripts have completed executing? Like saving it to a variable or output to a file.
[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could redirect the output to a file by using something like `your_command > output` where `output` is the file location.

Note, that this will remove the output in your terminal.

In order to write to the file and to standard out you could use `your_command 2>&1 | tee outfile`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! would there be any way to capture the result of each Appium's test script after it is executed? Would it be possible to achieve this through method like driver.getLogs()?